# How to get subreport name from JasperReport object (.jasper compiled file) via API?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

There's a main report file containing subreports. It is compiled to .jasper and I access it by loading it into `JaserReport` class.

I am able to get fields and datasets trough

```
report.getMainDataset().getFields();
```

However I am unable to get subreports, I've been trying to get them trough the

```
report.getAllBands();
```

and then using the for clause

```
 for (int i = 0; i < bands.length; i++) {
            JRElement[] element = bands[i].getElements(); 
  }
```

This way I can get some `JRBaseSubreport` classes, and it is as far as I can get. I can access the elements of subreports, but can't get the names of subreports.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **can not get data in subreport** by only loading the main report into `JasperReport` object. This object only contains the main report and it's elements.

The element relative to the subreport is a [JRBaseSubreport](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/base/JRBaseSubreport.html), which has reference to data relative to subreport tag in main report, hence it does not contain the actual report object.

The subreport will be **loaded by the filler** depending on the expressions, you could actually load a different sub report depending on the values of your datasource so jasper report can't know what sub report to load until the report is filled.

But you can **access the expression** it will use to load the subreport and this maybe can be enough in your case

**Example on how to access the expression (subreport in first detail band)**

```
//I know the subreport is in first detail band so I access this directly 
JRBaseBand detailBand1 = (JRBaseBand) report.getDetailSection().getBands()[0];
List<JRChild> elements = detailBand1.getChildren(); //Get all children
for (JRChild child : elements) {
    if (child instanceof JRBaseSubreport){ //This is a subreport
        JRBaseSubreport subreport = (JRBaseSubreport)child;
        String expression= ""; //Lets find out the expression used
        JRExpressionChunk[] chunks = subreport.getExpression().getChunks();
        for (JRExpressionChunk c : chunks) {
            expression +=c.getText();
        }
        System.out.println(expression); 
        //Here you could do code to load the subreport into a JasperReport object
    }
}
```

With this data you can load the subreport manually into another `JasperReport` object and access name, fields etc. Naturally if you have a complex expression your code will need to reflect this (retrive parameters or data from datasource)